# Jquery ajax to custom php file: returning blank data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, mysql

I created a custom php file, put it in my folder. The files does insert some data to the database to a custom table i created.

```
require wp_path() . "/wp-load.php";
global $wpdb;
$favorite_table = $wpdb->prefix . "fav";
$wpdb->insert( $favorite_table, array( 'link' => $_POST['fav_link'], 'title'=> $_POST['title']) );
$lastid = $wpdb->insert_id;

echo $lastid;
function wp_path() {
    if (strstr($_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"], "/wp-content/")) {
        return preg_replace("/\/wp-content\/.*/", "", $_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]);
    }
    return preg_replace("/\/[^\/]+?\/themes\/.*/", "", $_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]);
}
```

what is calling this php file is a jquery ajax function from within my theme:

```
$.post(WPURLS.theme_directory_uri+'/favorite/fav.php', data).done(function(data ) {
      alert(data);
 }).fail(function() {      
 });
```

This insert into the database but doesn't return anything in the response, data is blank. while if i manually pasted the URL in browser (GET) i can see the $lastid displayed.

What am I doing wrong? I need to retrieve the response data $lastid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going on the wrong way.This will create difficulties and is NOT WORDPRESS STANDARD.Wordpress has a ajax technique to implement this.

Call the ajax from your page

```
<script>
var data = {
    'action': 'insert_data_customtable',
    'first_name': firstname,
    'last_name': lastname
};

// since 2.8 ajaxurl is always defined in the admin header and points to admin-ajax.php                 
jQuery.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: ajaxurl,
  dataType: "json",
  data: data,
  success: function(response) {
    console.log(response);
    ///response will return that you echo in function insert_data_customtable

  },
  error: function(response){
    alert(response);
  }
});

</script>
```

And write this in your functions.php

```
add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_insert_data_customtable", "insert_data_customtable");
dd_action("wp_ajax_insert_data_customtable", "insert_data_customtable");

function insert_data_customtable(){
    //Here is your code for insert into table
    $insertid=mysql_insert_id();

    echo json_encode($insertid);
    die();
}
```

Comment: but url:ajaxurl alone will not point to the php function that is inserting to my table. My url is: WPURLS.theme_directory_uri+'/favorite/fav.php' , i need to reach fav.php

Comment: nevermind I didn't notice the 'action:method_name' part. Thanks man that was very helpful!

Comment: Great ! As you find it useful